# I cannot run any cmd in WinEdt

Tags: miktex, winedt

I am using WinEdt(Build: 20110315  (v. 6.0)) with MiKTeX(2.9.4282). I have used it for years, it was all OK one hour ago. But now I cannot click the button to run the cmd. I do not know what I did any thing wrong. When I **click** the pdflatex icon(or any others cmd, next the recycle bin icon), it simply says in the windows

> Startup folder: E:\Poster_Li
>
> Error launching Console Application PDFLaTeX Command Line:
>   pdflatex.exe "filename.tex" Startup Folder: E:\Poster_Li
>
> Invalid folder name (above in English, this line is given in local language).

It seems that the Startup folder is fixed to E:\Poster_Li. I have deleted E:\Poster_Li. On the other hand, I can still use cmd line such as pdflatex filename.tex to compile files (I do not like this way.).

Comment: It sounds like you have a "portable" MikTeX installation whose root directory is located on the (logical) E: drive. Did you maybe mount another USB drive and, as a result, the physical device that was assigned to E: is now at F: (or somewhere else altogether)? If so, try to reboot the machine in the standard setup and check if the Miktex distribution is back under E:.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the comment. I am not using portable MikTeX. After reboot, the problem remains.

Comment: @Holle Thank you so much. Your trick works! Yes, I deleted some file when it is opened in WinEdt. After that when I open any file the problem happens.

Comment: @Holle Please turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WinEdt the startup folder is not fixed. The startup folder is the folder where the mainfile is located. But you have to tell WinEdt which your mainfile is: Open filename.tex and execute WinEdt->Project->Set Main File. Maybe you renamed or moved you folder without setting the mainfile.